# Using XSLT1 how can I simply assign an incrementing value beginning with 1?

Tags: xslt-1.0

In my XSL script I have the following:

```
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
```

The start of the template is:

```
<xsl:template match="Student | Reader">
    <xsl:if test="self::Student">
         <hr/>
    </xsl:if>
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>containter-student-slip</xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

I want the `id` to simply be a numerical value, starting at `1` and  up.

I realise it is no good using `position()` because it is relative to  both matching element types.

Using XSLT1 how can I simply assign an incrementing value beginning with 1?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `position()`, you could probably* just change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MeetingWorkBook/Meeting">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TFGW/BibleReadingItem/Readers/Reader | AYFM/StudentItem/Students/Student"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively*, it may be possible to use `xsl:number`.

---

(*) Of course, without a reproducible example these are merely guesses.

Comment: The initial suggestion you made works well.